# MIPS: Unable to print an array of records that consist of Strings and integers?

Tags: assembly, mips, record

So I'm supposed read and store 4 records that consist of an employee's name (String), age (int), and salary (int) into an array. I believe that I have successfully done that part, but I'm having trouble printing all of the records in successive order. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Sample Input:

```
emp1
1
1
emp2
2
2
emp3
3
3
emp4
4
4
```

Current Output:

```
emp1
1
1
emp1
1
1
emp1
1
1
emp1
1
1

-- program is finished running --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `loopB`, put the address of `array` into some unused register (e.g. `$t2`), and then use it whenever you need to access a record:

```
la $t2,array
loopB:
    li $v0,4        # print name
    move $a0,$t2
    ....
    li $v0, 1        # print age
    lw $a0,4($t2)
    ....
    addiu $t2,$t2,12  # point to next element
    addi $t1, $t1, -1
    bgtz $t1, loopB
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you!